# TLS1.3 Browser compatibility on older windows versions like 7 or 8

Tags: operating-system, tls1.3

How browsers like chrome and edge are establishing tls1.3 connection on windows8 but Windows8 lacks the security patches and updates required for secure TLS 1.3.

Which cryptographic libraries they used.

Can anyone explain in detail how browsers establish tls1.3 on older versions of windows.